# ANTLR4 problem with balanced parentheses grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm doing some experiments with ANTLR4 with this grammar:

```
srule   
    :  '(' srule ')'
    | srule srule
    | '(' ')';
```

this grammar is for the language of balanced parentheses.
The problem is that when I run antlr with this string: `(()))(`

This string is obviously wrong but antlr simply return this AST:

[image: AST]

It seems to stop when it finds the wrong parenthesis, but no error message returns. I would like to know more about this behavior. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The parser recognises `(()))` and then stops. If you want to force the parser to consume all tokens, "anchor" your test rule with the `EOF` token:

```
parse_all
 : srule EOF
 ;
```

Btw, it's always a good idea to include the `EOF` token in the entry point (entry rule) of your grammar.